# Five child elements take up 100% of the container's width each has margin

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new with responsive design and I'm struggling with the below issue.

I am creating a search/filter bar that needs to have five filters per row with 1% margins on the edges and 2% margins in between.  I thought this would be easy; if I make the width of the filter 18% and give each one a 1% left and right margin, that would be 20% × 5 = 100%.  Unfortunately, this is causing the fifth filter to go to the next line.

Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/L3sd5qLo/

```css
.search-bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.search-bar__filter {
  margin: 0 1%;
  width: 18%;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <select id="filter1" class="search-bar__filter">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="filter2" class="search-bar__filter">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="filter3" class="search-bar__filter">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="filter4" class="search-bar__filter">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="filter5" class="search-bar__filter">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="filter6" class="search-bar__filter">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**EDIT** I wanted to show that the sixth item should go to a new line, having the first five child items taking up 100% of the lines width.

Comment: By the way there are 6 items not 5 in your example.

Comment: @Pangloss Yes, I wanted to show that the sixth item should go to a new line, having the first five child items taking up 100% of the lines width.

Comment: It's rather complicated, since `<select>` is rendered as inline block, which means it also renders white space ~4px between. You can float them as suggested in the answer, or use flexbox, css table etc.

Comment: @Pangloss also, removing space between items solves the issue https://jsfiddle.net/djmaos33/

Comment: FYI - https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @Pangloss thank you! your answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to add float left to .search-bar__filter:

```
.search-bar__filter {
 margin: 0 1%;
 width: 18%;
 float:left; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to avoid using floats for now, though.

Comment: Then you have to use flexbox

Answer (score 1):

This problem is much easier to solve using flex. It's supported by all modern browsers—older browsers can be supported by using prefixes or polyfills.

```
.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.search-bar__filter {
  flex: 0 auto;
  flex: space-between;
  min-width: x;
}
```

### References

- Flex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex
- Caniuse: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox
- Poly fill: https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

Comment: Thank you! I want to try to manage the 4px whitespace for now, though.

Comment: You don't have to use space-between, there are different options to choose from. The MDN reference I posted has has live examples of what each option renders. Also, you can still use margins and padding on the flex elements.